# Proofs of the three-positive number inequality conditional

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

For positive $x$, $y$ and $z$: if $(x + y) > z$, then both $(y + z ) > x$ and $(z + x) > y$. I am looking for proofs of the above three positive numbers inequality conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Counter example: $x = 7, y = 10, z = 1$. What you are probably asking is:

If$x+y > z$ then $y+z > x$ **or** $z+x > y$ must be true. We can prove this statement by contradiction. Assume otherwise, $y+z \le x$,**and**  $z+x \le y$ $\implies x+y+2z \le x+y \implies 2z \leq 0 \implies z \le 0$, contradiction.

Comment: DeepSea weakened my false misstatement transforming it to a truth. Their method was to weaken my consequent. A universalized conditional can also be weakened by strengthening the antecedent. Is their a nice way to do that? Thanks to DeepSea and to all who think about this.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=3, y=z=1$ then $3 + 1 > 1$ but $1 + 1 \not> 3$.